# How do I get to display the last date that has a corresponding value in another column in excel?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a excel spreadsheet with dates in one column, and results/values in another column (not next to each other, but on the same sheet). I want to set up a little summary table that will display the last date that had a corresponding result in the results column, since the latest date does not always have results available immediately. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with an array formula.

```
=MAX(IF(B3:B12<>"";A3:A12;0))
```

Important with an array formula is that you finish entering by Control + Shift + Enter!! The formula will then be automatically enclosed in curly brackets. If you press only enter it will work as a normal formula.

What the formula will do:

The `if` will go through the range and if the cell content meets your condition then it puts the value from the according cell in the second array into his result array otherwise it puts in 0.

Then the `MAX` command is working on the resulting array. Important is that the arrays used in the array formula are the same size!

[image: Excel Table with last result date]